# Alexa ignoring "arrive" in sample utterance and mapping to wrong intent

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I have two intents set up for my Alexa Skill, `NextTrainIntent` and `TrainArrivalIntent`.  In my sample utterances, I map them like this:

```
NextTrainIntent what is the next train to {DestinationCity}
NextTrainIntent what's the next train to {DestinationCity}
NextTrainIntent when is the next train to {DestinationCity}
NextTrainIntent when is the next train from {OriginCity}
NextTrainIntent when is the next train from {OriginCity} to {DestinationCity}
NextTrainIntent when is the next train
TrainArrivalIntent when does train {TrainNumber} arrive at {DestinationCity}
TrainArrivalIntent when does train {TrainNumber} arrive 
TrainArrivalIntent when does train {TrainNumber} get in 
...
```

When I test this using Amazon's Service Simulator, if I enter the following utterance as text: **"when does train 9306 arrive", the 
Service Request json shows that it has mapped the utterance to the NextTrainIntent, even though it is an exact match** for a sample utterance for the TrainArrivalIntent:

```
"request": {
  "type": "IntentRequest",
  "requestId": "EdwRequestId.ccafa51d-38de-4500-b17b-f94bbee1ad93",
  "intent": {
    "name": "NextTrainIntent",
```

If, however, I test the utterance: "When does train 9305 get in", it maps correctly to TrainArrivalIntent.

```
"request": {
  "type": "IntentRequest",
  "requestId": "EdwRequestId.7a415e55-14b3-4789-9a83-0f6cf2f16a6c",
  "intent": {
    "name": "TrainArrivalIntent",
```

What's wrong here?  In this case, the presence of the word "arrive" is critical to discerning between the two intents.  However, Alexa seems to ignore it.  How can I make it "arrive" get used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the "what is the" and the "when is" statements from my samples and it started working.

```
NextTrainIntent next train from {OriginCity} to {DestinationCity}
NextTrainToFromIntent next train to {DestinationCity} from {OriginCity}
TrainArrivalIntent train {TrainNumber} arrive at {DestinationCity}
TrainArrivalIntent train {TrainNumber} arrive 
TrainArrivalIntent train {TrainNumber} get in 
TrainArrivalIntent train {TrainNumber} arrive at {DestinationCity}
TrainArrivalIntent train {TrainNumber} get in to {DestinationCity}
TrainArrivalIntent train number {TrainNumber} arrive at {DestinationCity}
TrainArrivalIntent train number {TrainNumber} get in to {DestinationCity}
TrainArrivalIntent train number {TrainNumber} arrive 
TrainArrivalIntent train number {TrainNumber} get in
```

Because there are a few other changes to the speech samples above, I'm not positive that removing the question prefixes is what fixed the problem.  As always with machine learning, you often can't get an answer to "why" something works.  Whatever the reason, the above sample utterances did make the utterance in the question get recognized properly.

Comment: do you need the intent name in the sample utterance? i.e. "TrainArrivalIntent train number {TrainNumber} get in", do you need the TrainArrivalIntent part..?

Comment: Yes, but only because that is the identifier Amazon uses to match it to the right intent.  Those are not really part of the sample utterance text.  The sample text starts after the identifier.